# Printing only the file name after searching a pattern in the first line (using grep and head)

Tags: grep, head

So I'm a beginner and i have a project due next week. I have to print only the filename of the files that contain `#!/bin/bash` on the first line. So far I tried this

```
head -n 1 $filename | grep -l "pattern"
```

but when I execute it instead of the name of the files I receive

```
(standard input)
```

Like I said, I'm a beginner and so far I'm familiar with simple commands. So I would like to know where I f****** up and if there is a way of acheiving what I want without using harder commands like `awk`.

```
for fis in  find -perm -a+x -name "*.sh" -type f
do
head -n 1 $fis | grep -l "#!/bin/bash"
done
```

Comment: First, edit your question and use codeblocks. Second, add sample text and the expected output again using codeblocks.

Comment: You probably know that your command alone will examine only one file. Do you have a loop behind it? Or a find? Also, doing that will be very simple with awk, I must say :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, this is my first post and I don t really know how to use this platform... i hope that now my post is better. Any other suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: @Quasímodo yes, i do have a `for` to select only the executable files with the format *.sh

Comment: @Quasímodo I edited the loop in the initial question. I m a little bit skeptical of using awk because i never used it before but if it is the only way, that I will do it

Comment: Please consider 
[Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 4):

In GNU `grep` you can use the `--label` option to set the label/filename if the input comes from stdin.

Instead of using an outer loop with a command substitution, you could use the `-exec` action to start a small script to loop over the filenames and execute the commands.

```
find -perm -a+x -name "*.sh" -type f -exec sh -c '
  for fis; do
    head -n1 "$fis" | grep --label="$fis" -Fl "#!/bin/bash"
  done
' sh {} +
```

I added the `-F` option to `grep` since we're looking for a fixed string.

Comment: Whitespace is allowed after `#!`, so maybe take `-F` out again, and search for `#![[:space:]]*/bin/bash`

Answer (score 2):

I know you have blacklisted awk, but for other people seeking help who come across your question, this is a quite efficient way to print the names of the executable `.sh` files that contain `#!/bin/bash` in their first line:

```
find . -perm -a+x -name '*.sh' -type f -exec \
    awk 'NR == 1{ if ($0 == "#!/bin/bash") print FILENAME; exit }' {} \;
```

Or, to print the name of files that have `#!/bin/bash` in their first line without further restrictions, drop the `-perm` and `-name` options:

```
find . -type f -exec awk ...
```

Comment: @steeldriver More than that, it's the correct way, otherwise files with `#!/bin/bash` in 2nd line or after (and not in the 1st line) would also be printed. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: @steeldriver True as well! I've set it as Community Wiki in case you see any more possible improvement.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -perm -a+x -name '*.sh' -type f |
    while IFS= read -r file; do
        test -f "$file" || continue
        if head -n 1 "$file" | grep -qFx '#!/bin/bash'; then
            echo "$file"
        fi
    done
```

Comment: YES!! oh my god thank you so much... I can t express in words how grateful I am. this works!!

Comment: @Laura I modified the files it is workingt on. Freddy's `find` approach is less readable but safer (regarding "evil" characters in file and directory names).

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to read the output of a command using a loop without a pipe. Not sure what the point of testing for `file` being a file is when `find` is outputting file names.

Comment: @EdMorton That is not about testing the file object type again but about detecting problems resulting from newlines in path names as that is not a safe `-print0` solution.

Comment: If your file names can contain newlines then `test -f "$file" || continue` isn't a solution as it'll silently not test real files output by `find` and will let `head ...` execute on files that weren't output by `find` but might exist and share a common pre-newline part with the real file names (eg. find outputs `foo\nbar.sh` and there's a file named `foo` in the directory). IMHO you should just say "this won't work if your file names contain newlines" and get rid of that test line.

Answer (score 0):

with `-n` and passing multiple files the output will be in this format:

`file_name:line_number:matched_text`

`-x` matches the whole line

`grep '#!/bin/bash' -nx *.sh |cut -d ':' -f 1,2 | grep ":1$" | cut -d ':' -f 1`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I just tried it and it displays the numar of files that contains the pattern on the first line... i need the name of the filles :(

Comment: no this is correct, could you please try again? I added some details.

Comment: @Quasímodo no the output will have only lines with `#!/bin/bash` from first `grep`.

Comment: @Quasímodo yes, I edited. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I really appreciate it and hopefully it will help others, it just didn't work for my program..

Comment: @Laura thanks but what is the issue? this is just `grep` and `cut` should work

Comment: I don't know... but the code from the other person that answered my questions worked immediately.

Comment: Maybe this doesn't work with the rest of my program, I really don't know. Programming is way harder than I thought..

Comment: @EdMorton if multiple files passed to `grep -n` the output will include the filenames too, as I have mentioned in the answer. but we can add `-H` (not `-h`) to make it more clear. Thanks for other points, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is very late to the party, but I've been doing exactly the same thing, and have had good results with this:

```
find . -perm -a+x -name "*.sh" -exec \
    bash -c 'grep -q "pattern" < <(head -n 1 "$1")' _ {} \; -printf '%p\n'
```

As  understand it, the `-q` flag prevents writing to standard output, allowing you to print the filename (`%p` from `find -printf`).

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob
zmodload zsh/system
bash_shebang_pattern=$'\\#! #(/usr/bin/env ##|(/usr(/local|)|/opt/gnu|)/bin/)bash[ \n]*'
improperly_named_bash_scripts=(
  **/*.sh(ND.L+11f[a+x]e['
    sysread -s80 shebang < $REPLY &&
      [[ $shebang = $~bash_shebang_pattern ]]
  '])
)
print -rl -- "These executable files have a .sh extension even though they're bash scripts:" $improperly_named_bash_scripts
```

That's widening a bit the possibilities of bash shebang, but note that possibilities are infinite if you want to consider BSD/GNU's `env -S` like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env --split-str=-u\_BASH_ENV\_-u\_ENV\_-u\_POSIXLY_CORRECT\_-u\_LC_ALL\_PATH=/opt/gnu/bin:${PATH}\_LC_CTYPE=C\_LC_COLLATE=C\_bash\_-o\_errexit\_-o\_nounset\_-o\_pipefail\_--
```

Which some might prefer over:

```
#! /bin/bash -
```

(let alone `#!/bin/bash` which [strictly speaking is *incorrect*](/q/351729)) to sanitize the environment a bit.

Details:

- `**/` any level of subdirectories.
- `*.sh` files whose name ends in `.sh` (note: that includes the hidden file whose name *is* `.sh`).
- `(ND.L+11f[a+x]e['code'])`: glob qualifiers:

  - `N`: nullglob
  - `D`: dotglob (include hidden files)
  - `.`: regular files only (no directory, symlink, fifo, device...)
  - `L+11`: `L`ength greater than 11 bytes (the size of `#!/bin/bash`)
  - `f[a+x]`: for which the permissions include `x` for `a`ll.
  - `e['code']`: runs the code to decide whether the file (in `$REPLY`) should be selected.
- `sysread -s80` only read the first 80 bytes. Should be enough even for a `#! /usr/bin/env   bash` one. Not one line, as those could be huge for binary files which are not guaranteed to contain newline characters.